# Why do I get an error "object of type 'HttpResponseRedirect' has no len()"?

Tags: django, django-generic-views

In my Django app i have a class-based view that inherits ListView. get_queryset method is overriden this way:

```
def get_queryset(self):
        if not 'anonymous_nickname' in self.request.session:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        filters = {}
        if self.request.user.is_anonymous():
            filters['allow_anonymous_access'] = True
        return CoopRoom.objects.filter(**filters)
```

in order not to let user see list of rooms when he wants to reach them without entering any data on the main page. But instead of performing this redirect:

```
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

i get an error "object of type 'HttpResponseRedirect' has no len()". I cannot see the reason why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `get_queryset()` method should return a queryset (like you do in your second `return` statement)  and *not* an `HttpResponseRedirect` !

Instead of returning the `HttpResponseRedirect` you can either throw a 404 exception (`raise Http404`) or return an empty queryset with `return CoopRoom.objects.none()`.